# Looking for a simple hatching algorithm

Tags: polygon, algorithm, filling

If I have an arbitrary polygon, and wish to hatch it with lines at a given angle and spacing, is there a simple low-level algorithm which will return the set of hatch lines inside the polygon?

Comment: I think you need to define your metric for "simple".  Calculating the lines *is* simple, but the simplicity of intersecting them with the base figure depends on what other tools you have available, and how you feel about simultaneous linear equations in two variables.

Comment: Well, less brute-force than my current proposed method, which is to render a viewport full of hatches, then cut it down using GEOS's intersection function against the polygon …

Comment: That's as simple as it gets, unless you want to use matrix algebra to solve the intersection of the hatch segments with the polygon boundary segments.

Answer (score 4):

Vince's comments led me to look again at [Shapely](http://toblerity.org/shapely/project.html) in Python, and it can do it. In short, the method I used was:

- get the bounding box of the page/object you want
- calculate the diagonal of this box, as this will be the minimum length your hatch lines need to be
- draw a square array of horizontal lines centred on the bounding box's centre, each spaced suitably apart
- rotate these lines to the desired angle
- clip them to the bounding box.

Somewhat crude example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# shapely_hatch - simple hatching function demo
# produces WKT of a 45° hatched crescent to stdout
# scruss — 2014-04-13 — WTFPL (srsly)

from shapely.geometry import box, MultiLineString, Point
from shapely.affinity import rotate
from shapely import speedups
from math import sqrt

# enable Shapely speedups, if possible
if speedups.available:
    speedups.enable()

def hatchbox(rect, angle, spacing):
    """
    returns a Shapely geometry (MULTILINESTRING, or more rarely,
    GEOMETRYCOLLECTION) for a simple hatched rectangle.

    args:
    rect - a Shapely geometry for the outer boundary of the hatch
           Likely most useful if it really is a rectangle

    angle - angle of hatch lines, conventional anticlockwise -ve

    spacing - spacing between hatch lines

    GEOMETRYCOLLECTION case occurs when a hatch line intersects with
    the corner of the clipping rectangle, which produces a point
    along with the usual lines.
    """

    (llx, lly, urx, ury) = rect.bounds
    centre_x = (urx + llx) / 2
    centre_y = (ury + lly) / 2
    diagonal_length = sqrt((urx - llx) ** 2 + (ury - lly) ** 2)
    number_of_lines = 2 + int(diagonal_length / spacing)
    hatch_length = spacing * (number_of_lines - 1)

    # build a square (of side hatch_length) horizontal lines
    # centred on centroid of the bounding box, 'spacing' units apart
    coords = []
    for i in range(number_of_lines):
        # alternate lines l2r and r2l to keep HP-7470A plotter happy ☺
        if i % 2:
            coords.extend([((centre_x - hatch_length / 2, centre_y
                          - hatch_length / 2 + i * spacing), (centre_x
                          + hatch_length / 2, centre_y - hatch_length
                          / 2 + i * spacing))])
        else:
            coords.extend([((centre_x + hatch_length / 2, centre_y
                          - hatch_length / 2 + i * spacing), (centre_x
                          - hatch_length / 2, centre_y - hatch_length
                          / 2 + i * spacing))])
    # turn array into Shapely object
    lines = MultiLineString(coords)
    # Rotate by angle around box centre
    lines = rotate(lines, angle, origin='centroid', use_radians=False)
    # return clipped array
    return rect.intersection(lines)

# pipe-separated output; can be read by QGIS
print 'ID| WKT'
page = box(1000, 1000, 6000, 6000)
hatching = hatchbox(page, 45, 50)
circle = Point(2500, 2500).buffer(1000)
circle1 = Point(2000, 2500).buffer(700)
crescent = circle.difference(circle1)
crescent_hatch = crescent.intersection(hatching)
print '1|', crescent_hatch
```

The output, when graphed, looks like this:

[image: hatch example plot]

Comment: My interests have moved from GIS, but a further refinement on this technique is to create a multipolygon of rectangles `[width, diagonal * 1.1]` spaced `2*width` apart, rotate it, then intersected. For physical pen plotter devices, this has a nice side effect of creating a [boustrophedon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon) without ugly code as above. There's always the risk of creating a null geometry if a line just touches a corner with either method, though